# Windows installer not completing the installation

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I am using Windows 7 64-bit with NTFS file system. While trying to install Ubuntu with the Windows installer it's starting to download a file, but it stops downloading at about 45%. Please guide me through the troubleshooting.

Comment: Windows installer does not work for version 13.04 or later.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install Wubi for running Ubuntu in Windows, then install Ubuntu 12.04 because Wubi is not supported for Ubuntu 13.04. Also Ubuntu 12.04 has the advantage of being a Long Term Support release that is supported by updates until April, 2017. The Windows installer for Wubi, called wubi.exe, is a 2.4MB file that you can download from the ubuntu.com website.